# What is the difference between passing a ref as a property and passing it as a prop？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`React.forwardRef creates a React component that forwards the ref attribute it receives to another component below in the tree`

```
import { forwardRef, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}

function Parent() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const onClick = () => {
    ref.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child ref={ref} />
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
    </>
  );
}

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} type="text" />;
});
```

However, I find that I can also achive that in this way:

```
import { forwardRef, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}

function Parent() {
  const ref = useRef();
  const onClick = () => {
    ref.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Child myRef={ref} /> // pass the ref through props
      <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
    </>
  );
}

const Child = ({ myRef }) => {
  return <input ref={myRef} type="text" />;
};
```

Here is the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-elbakyan-gugmyv?file=/src/App.js

I'd like to know what the difference between these two implementations is, and does it mean that `forwardRef` is no longer necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do that, it works just fine. It's especially a useful technique if you need multiple refs to elements in the child component, or if you want to give them specific names so that it's clear what they will refer to - e.g. `inputRef` and `submitBtnRef`. However [it is generally discouraged](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) as it is considered to break encapsulation.

The advantage of `forwardRef` is that one can use the standard `ref` "prop", as if [referencing a DOM element](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) or [a class component instance](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component). It does allow the component author to use function component syntax but still expose a `ref`. The purpose of a `ref` in the JSX element is clear without reading much of the component documentation: it exposes a handle to imperatively interact with the component. Using the name `ref` also aids in refactoring from `<input ref={myRef}>` to `<CustomInput ref={myRef}>`.